# Hexo server and deploy can not synchronize

Tags: hexo

I'm a beginner to hexo, I use `hexo s -g` to check my github.io at local, everything is right. 
 But when I use `hexo d -g -m "commit message"` to deploy my github.io, something will lose at the site. I check my commit on github, it has been submmited. Does anyone have the problem too? Or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that use `hexo clean` before `hexo generate` and then use `hexo deploy`, it can be synchronized both localhost and github.io side.